# Splash Screen Not Working As Expected - Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

First it shows the splash screen, then it fades to black and then it shows this screen...

[image]

And then finally it navigates to app's home screen.

It's unsatisfying.

How do I get rid of the black and the above blank screen?

My code is as follows:

> 1. Splash screen activity

```
[Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/Splash",
            ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var startupWork = new Task(() =>
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity))));

        startupWork.Start();
    }
}
```

> 2. styles.xml:

```
<style name="Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

> 3. splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/SplashBackground" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Apply the theme/windowBackground to the MainActivity and do not use a separate   "splash" activity as you are doing nothing with that activity

Comment: @SushiHangover The problem with that is that the splash screen theme appears in the background throughout the app.

Comment: Once the app is running, then clear it: `Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Android.Resource.Color.Black);`

Comment: That's handy. I thought I'd need to change the theme. Is there a way to hide the UI until it's ready to show?

Comment: See my answer, let me know if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement 3 steps :

1. in your MainActivity.cs 
   MainLauncher =false,
2. Create a class in AppName.Android project
   (Ex : MySplashScreen.cs)
3. in MySplashScreen.cs edit same this code. (MainLauncher must true)

> ```
> [Activity(Label = "ApplicationName",
>         Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
>         MainLauncher =true,
>         NoHistory =true
>         ),]
>     public class MySplashScreen : Activity
>     {
>         protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>         {
>             base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>             // Create your application here
>             StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Not using a Task seems to have removed the moment of black screen, but I'm still seeing the half constructed, blue UI.

Comment: Would you like to video the video you took when you run the application?
Can you upload this video for 2-3 seconds in a simple way online and share me link

Answer (score 0):

"Converting my comments to an answer..."

Apply the theme that contains a `windowBackground` to the `MainActivity` and do not use a separate "splash" activity as you are doing nothing with that activity

#### Example Theme (just a subset):

```
<style name="Theme.ASushiApp.Main" parent="Theme.ASushiApp.Base">
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_layer</item>
</style>
```

In your layout for the `MainActvity` set the root ViewGroup to visibility to invisible.

Or you can set the background to `@android:color/transparent` and add a indeterminate `ProgressBar` to show a spinning progress wheel.

The goal here is to allow the background image in your theme to continue to be shown while you setup the app.

Then on your `OnCreate` do the bare minimum that you have to on the UI thread and then start a `Task`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    ~~~
    // setup toolbar/actionbar, FindViewById assignments, etc..
    ~~~
    new Task(InitalSetup).Start();
}
```

In the background, do the rest of your setup and finally, in the UI/main thread, hide the progress indictor or set the root container ViewGroup to visible and set the background (Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource) to a solid color to clear the image you used in your theme.

```
async void InitalSetup()
{
    // running on a background thread...

    // setup db, any adapters, listeners, AdView handlers, etc... 
    // everything but direct UI changes, do those at the end on the UI/Main thread
    ~~~

    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        // finish setup on the UI items that have to run on UI thread, ie: adapter assignments
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);

        rootViewGroupContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        // Or
        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Android.Resource.Color.Black);
    });
```